# Pyplot cannot plot Regression

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to emulate the very simple example

```
N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radiuses

print(type(x),type(y))
print('training samples ',len(x),len(y))
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

this shows

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
training samples  50 50
```

as expected and the plot shows up as well. Now I am trying to plot the results of `GradientBoostingRegressor` as

```
base_regressor = GradientBoostingRegressor()
base_regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_base = base_regressor.predict(X_test)

print(type(X_train),type(y_train))
print('training samples ',len(X_train),len(y_train))
print(type(X_test),type(y_pred_base))
print('base samples ',len(X_test),len(y_pred_base))

plt.figure()

plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, c="k", label="training samples")
plt.plot(X_test, y_pred_base, c="g", label="n_estimators=1", linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel("data")
plt.ylabel("target")
plt.title("Base Regression")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

note that `X_train`, `y_train`, and `X_test` are all numpy arrays. For the above code I get

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
training samples  74067 74067
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
base samples  166693 166693
```

but the plot does not show up and I get the error

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

at

```
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, c="k", label="training samples")
```

but as seen in the output, `x` and `y` are of the same size and type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: rather than printing `len(X_test)` could you print `X_test.shape` ?

Comment: thanks for suggesting this, now i get `training samples  (74067, 163) (74067,)` and `base samples  (166693, 163) (166693,)`

Comment: which makes sense as for my training dimension, i have 163 columns

Comment: i guess my point is, how do i plot `y_train` against `X_train` and `y_pred_base` against `X_test`?

Comment: i want to see these side by side

Comment: reshape your `y`. Do `np.reshape(y, (y.shape[0],1))`

Comment: thanks, will this do an inplace reshape?

Comment: No, won't do it inplace. Returns a new array

Comment: i still get the same error. and by the way, why do we have `y.shape[0],1`?

Comment: what is `,1` for?

Comment: Well, how is your training data organized? You say X_train and y_train are 2-D arrays, OK so how do you want them to be plotted? `plt.scatter` will plot a 1-D y array against a 1-D x array on a 2-D graph.

Comment: i want to chart y against x for training data and then compare that to another chart of y against x for test data (after prediction). does that make sense? i just want to compare the shape/distribution

Answer (score 3):

Your X_train array is 2-dimensional, with 163 columns for each sample. You can't plot your y_train array, which is only 1-dimensional, against the entire X_train array. Similarly for the y_pred_base plot against X_test.

You will have to choose one of the columns in the X arrays to plot against, editing your code something like this:

```
plt.scatter(X_train[:, 17], y_train, c="k", label="training samples")
plt.plot(X_test[:, 17], y_pred_base, c="g", label="n_estimators=1", linewidth=2)
```

Your dependent variables (X) live in a 163-dimensional space. Each y value depends on the corresponding x-value from each of these dimensions. A simple 2-dimensional scatter or line plot just can't display all of that information at once.

One thing you could do is find out which of the x variables your y values depend on most. You can access this with the `base_regressor.feature_importances_` attribute. There's an example in the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-regression-py). Then you could make a plot against the most important ones. You could do this in multiple dimensions using a 3D scatter plot or in even higher dimensions with something like [corner.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/corner/1.0.0)

Comment: makes sense. i still dont understand how to achieve what i want to see. basically, i want to chart y against x for training data and then compare that to another chart of y against x for test data (after prediction). does that make sense? i just want to compare the shape/distribution

Comment: I edited my answer to include an explanation, since it was too long to fit in a comment. Hope that helps :)